# Ubuntu compatibility on Dell Precision T5500

Tags: dell, compatibility

I am using a Dell Precision T5500 which came pre-installed with Red Hat. During the course of time, the serial key for Red Hat was lost, due to that it is getting difficult to install or update the software.
I am thinking to remove Red Hat and install Ubuntu, before doing it, I want to make sure that the Dell T5500 is compatible with Ubuntu. Will it work normally?

Comment: You should boot from a Live system and see if everything is working as expected.

Comment: To do live boot, create a USB startup disk of Ubuntu. Once you boot using it, it give you option called try Ubuntu without installing. Run it and see it for yourself.
If ok, there only you will get option to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run a [LiveCD, LiveDVD or LiveUSB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) and see if everything works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We have very good way to find it out on this ubuntu site  http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is fully compatible. Go ahead. Installing through LiveCD is recommended.